# Considering "quantum swapping", are there any particles currently on earth that are entangled with particles on the moon?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, space, nature

If quantum swapping allows for entanglement to be swapped between two particles that have never spatially interacted, then would it stand to reason that when a rock comes from the moon, that some particles still on the moon may now be entangled with some particles on earth? Or is quantum swapping something that can only happen in careful conditions in a lab, and not accidentally in nature?

Comment: from reading about this,  example https://www.nature.com/articles/srep09333 , it is the second case "can only happen in careful conditions in a lab, and not accidentally in nature?"

Comment: @annav thanks so much, this is exactly what i need, i really appreciate it!